# How to make any listItem under an ul sortable and enable dropping a new list item anywhere under the ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have some items that could be dragged into a sortable list. How can I make it so that the item I drag can be placed anywhere inside the  element, even in the childs ul element. For example

```
<li id='target'>Item To be dropped </li>

<ul class='ui-sortable id='root'>
   <li> <div>position 1</div> </li>
   <li> <div>position 2</div> </li>
   <li> 
       <div>position 3></div> 
       <ul> 
          <li> position 3.a </li>
          <li> position 3.b </li>
       </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to make it so that each list item under root can be placed anywhere under root, and the target listItem can be dropped anywhere under the root? I'm have it working on only 1 level deep under the root, but having trouble making it work for n-level deep. Any help guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for this http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/